# How to show full screen view within a UITSplitViewController app?

Tags: ios, uipopovercontroller, modalviewcontroller

I have an application based off of the UISplitView project template. It works great.

But now i'd like to have a full-screen view, like a modal view. How can this be done so that it takes up the entire screen space?

If not possible, i suppose i could create a UIPopover view and make it fill up the whole screen, though i'd really like the view to take up the entire screen (without the popover type of view bordering).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something, but can't you just create a view controller and present it modally?  It works fine with splitview controllers.  In other words:

```
    MyModalController *mc = [[MyModalController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyModalController" bundle:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:mc animated:YES];
    [mc autorelease];
```

Comment: i will try this out when I'm working on this app again. But in the meant time, wouldn't this modal view be displayed ONLY WITHIN the view from which is was invoked (master view or content detail view) rather than the entire split view?